# Regex Replace HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Having some problems with regex. 
I have long string

```
str = '<div class=\"edit\">some text here
   <div><br></div>
   <div>then other row</div>
   <div><br></div> 
   <div>and one more</div>
</div>
<div class=\"edit\">some text here
<div><br></div><div>then other row</div></div>'
```

and I want to have:

```
<div class\"edit\">some text here<br>then other row<br>and one more<div>
<div class=\"edit"\>some text here<br>then other row<div>
```

And i trying do this:

```
str = str.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/ig, "<br>");
str = str.replace(/<div>/ig, "<br>");
str = str.replace(/<\/div>/ig, "");
```

Comment: What language/technology are you using for replace?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.  [RegEx can only match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language](http://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/930393)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it is bad idea to transform html-strings using regexp. There is DOM for that. Nevertheless this one seems to work:

```
str = str.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/gi, '<br>')
         .replace(/<div>([^<]*)<\/div>/gi, '$1');
```

The resulting string is `"<div class="edit">some text here   <br>   then other row   <br>    and one more</div><div class="edit">some text here<br>then other row</div>"`